# How to interact with windows elements within selenium python code?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What is an easy(simple/clean) way to add few steps to interact with windows based elements within python selenium script?

eg:
Click a download button via selenium driver, change the file name and location and click save button on windows dialog.

Note:

- Downloads button is just an example. I pretty much want to know a common way to handle any kind of items.
- I do not want a way where they recommend a way to configure browser such that downloads happen automatically at a specific location on our system.

Way to execute my scenario:

- Keep this setting turned ON in chrome.
  Ask where to save each file before downloading.
- Website to try - https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/.
- Try downloading anything.

Comment: You can try Python implementation of [AutoIT](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoIt/) or [AutoHK](https://pyahk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: or http://robotframework.org/

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called Winium, remote driver implementation of Selenium for automating desktop applications. This could help you with this job.

You can spy ui using [Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinAuto/inspect-objects).

Find the samples at https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/wiki/Magic-Samples

Answer (score 1):

Try to use AUTO It, it will be useful in Interacting with windows based applications in selenium.

Check out here - https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html

Hope This Helps You.